# Find The General Solution Of $y''+n^2y=m$ m,n constants.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution of
>   $$y''+n^2y=m$$
>   and the solution satisfying the initial conditions
>   $$y(0)=1, y'(0)=0$$$$P(x)=0$$$$W=e^{-\int P(x)dx}=e^{-c}$$$$y_2=y_1\int \frac{W}{y_1^2}dx$$$$Y(x)=c_1(x)y_1+c_2(x)y_2$$$$0=c_1(x)y_1+c_2(x)y_2$$$$r(x)=c_1'(x)y_1'+c_2'(x)y_2'$$$$y''+by'+cy=Ae^{\gamma x}$$$$Y=Be^{\gamma x}$$$$y''+n^2y=0$$$$\lambda^2+n^2=0$$$$m=me^{0x},\alpha=0$$
>   But where to from here? I would like to arrive at values and/or equations for $c_1,c_2,y_1,y_2, A$ and $B$.Further
>   $$y''+n^2y=e^{imx}$$$$Y(x)=Be^{imx}, n^2\neq m^2$$$$Y(x)=Bxe^{imx},n^2=m^2$$$$y''+n^2y=\cos mx$$

Comment: Why not use Undetermined Coefficients? We have $y_c = c_1 \cos nt + c_2 \sin nt$ and choose $y_p = a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

($ y ' = \frac{\mathrm{d}y }{\mathrm{d} x} $)

$ (D^{2}+n^{2})y  = m $ , $y(0)=1 , y'(0)=0$

Equation $ (D^{2}+n^{2})y  = 0 $ 's solutions are $y = c_{1}\cos nx + c_{2} \sin nx$

so $ y_{c} =  c_{1}\cos nx + c_{2} \sin nx$

We know $ y_{p} =\frac{m}{n^{2}} $

$\therefore y = y_{c} + y_{p} =  \frac{n^{2} - m}{n^{2}} \cos nx + \frac{m}{n^{2}} $  (because of IC : $y(0)=1 , y'(0)=0$ )